when I am trying to create new next js project I get an error
Here is the error message I got
C:\Users\DELL>npx create-next-app@latest sprout-scribble
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-21T10_32_49_910Z-debug-0.log

screenshot of the error
Please help me install Next.js. I have already tried all the methods available on online. I have the latest version of Node.js installed on my system.
